# The best way to store large set of objects with efficient update/append operations

Tags: java, database, nosql, zip, storage

### What is my specific use case?

I have set of objects representing e. g. profiles. Objects can be modified (updated), deleted or added. Each object has several properties, but modification of single property value just marks the whole object as "modified" (so from persistence layer point of view, an object is atomic). There are no relations between the objects.

Size of such set is between **10 - 50000** (but theoretically there's no limit - user can append additional objects). Single object size is **up to 500KB** (but usually it will be smaller, about **60KB**).

Objects should be read and updated as fast as possible. There's also one more key requirement: they should be persisted on hard disk with possibility to copy or move them. My app is written in Java and run on Windows 7-10 OS.

### What was my initial approach?

I came to conclusion that each object can be easily represented as single JSON file. The problem lies in keeping such large set of files on a disk. Windows filesystem doesn't seem to be good at handling too many (even small) files.

Then I thought that my files can be stored in virtual filesystem. The first obvious solution was to pack them in **ZIP archive** in such way:

```
profiles.zip:
--- profile1.json
--- profile2.json
...
--- profile10000.json
```

It would be great solution in terms of portability and the read performance is also ok. BUT, it seems the new objects can't be appended to ZIP archive without copying all files stored in the archive... Or at least I didn't find a way to do it.

### What should I do then...?

I've searched for other solutions. I consider using:

- **Fast relational database** - but I feel it is like to take a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Especially I don't need to handle relations or transactions (I don't even need a server, it is only for one local user).
- **NoSQL object databases**, e.g. **MapDb** or **Nitrite** - it sounds ok, but I couldn't find any reliable comparisons or popularity ratings. It is important for me to pick a credible solution.
- Some other **virtual filesystems** that can be managed in Java? Maybe I missed something?

Could you provide any ideas or advices based on experience? I need **fast read/update** of **whole objects** in **large datasets** with **portability** (that can be achieved in **Java** and **Windows** OS).

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to answer the question unless we know the size of each object in memory. One suggestion I can give is to try hybrid frameworks which support in memory access as well as persistence to disk.

Ehcache is one of the frameworks which I think will work for you and it it easily supports 50000 objects in memory itself. Even Couchbase supports similar options and a flexibility of immediate or eventual persistence.

Comment: I forgot to add information about object's size (I updated my post) - it's between 50-500KB, but usually close to 50KB.